# FFmpeg infile path, my domain

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have a file located at `html://www.example.com/wp-content/music.mp3`

I've tested and confirmed ffmpeg is installed and have run

```
exec("ffmpeg -help",$output);
```

I successfully get an output.  Now i want to start converting but i cannot locate the file above.  I've tried

```
exec("ffmpeg -i html://www.example.com/wp-content/music.mp3",$output);

exec("ffmpeg -i home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-content/music.mp3",$output);
```

I get no output for either.  ffmpeg is located in `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`.

How do i solve?

Comment: try with `$output = shell_exec('ffmpeg -i home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-content/music.mp3'); echo $output;`

Comment: Nope nothing.  The file exists, what could be causing the problem?

Comment: first one, change html:// to http://, second one, write full path starting with "/" -> "/home..."

Comment: Changed both and no response?

Comment: try with `/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i input.mp3 2>&1`

Comment: Yes works, i get a response, says no such file or directory.

Comment: Thanks, i get a response now with my file!!  Thanks!

Comment: `with 2>&1` the error output redirects to normal output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect the error output (stderr) to response (stdout):

```
<?php
$command = "ffmpeg -i https://www.example/a.mp3 2>&1";
$output = shell_exec($command);

echo $output;
```